# Erro ao executar classe com parâmetro pelo main

Tags: java

Eu estou tentando compilar o meu código pelo cmd, passando o parâmetro da imagem(nome e formato). Mas ele me retorna esse erro.

```
java ImageSplit tileset.png

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at ImageSplit.main(ImageSplit.java:33)
```

O codigo é esse:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageSplit {

    private static int width = 0;
    private static int height = 0;
    private static final int tileSize = 16;

    private BufferedImage readImage(String caminho) {

        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    getClass().getResource(caminho).getFile()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImageSplit imageSplit = new ImageSplit();
        BufferedImage image = null; 
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Informe o parametro da imagem.");
            return;
        }
        image = imageSplit.readImage(args[1]);
        width = image.getWidth() / tileSize; // Col, tile
        height = image.getHeight() / tileSize; // Row, tile
        BufferedImage[] subImages = new BufferedImage[width * height];
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++) {
                subImages[i * width + j] = image.getSubimage(j * 16, i * 16, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<subImages.length; i++) {
            try {
                ImageIO.write(subImages[i], "tile" + i + ".png", new File("./Tiles"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E a imagem se encontra na mesma pasta da classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o erro esteja nesta linha:

```
image = imageSplit.readImage(args[1]);
```

Como você está passando apenas um argumento para o main(apenas o `tileset.png`), o correto é pegar o primeiro Índice do `args[]`, que é 0 e não 1. Altere conforme abaixo:

```
image = imageSplit.readImage(args[0]);
```

Em java, os índices de listas e arrays começam por 0 e vão até `tamanho da lista(array)-1`.

Comment: Isso deu certo, só não entendi porque não esta gravando as imagens.

Comment: @Roodrigo ai já é outro problema diferente da pergunta. Sugiro você encerrar esta pergunta marcando a resposta como aceita(clicando no `v`) e abrir uma nova pergunta com esta nova duvida. Não se esqueça de fornecer um **[mcve]** para que possamos testar o código :)

Comment: Downvoter, o que tem de errado que pode melhorar na resposta? Ou o voto foi só de implicância mesmo?